Get latest Modified date based on column value change in SQL
We have this Transmission_Status table:



Key_Value
FIELD
NEW_VALUE
DATE_MODIFIED




45
Transmission Status
Terminated
7/11/2024


45
Transmission Status
Terminated
5/15/2024


45
Transmission Status
Inactive
2/13/2022


45
Transmission Status
Inactive
2/13/2022


45
Transmission Status
Active
1/24/2022


45
Transmission Status
Active
12/20/2021


45
Transmission Status
Active
12/20/2021



We need the latest date modified when ever the NEW_VALUE column changes (in this case, changed from Inactive to Terminated).
Current query:
select 
    key_value, field,new_value, date_modified
from
    (select 
         key_value, field,new_value, date_modified,
         rank() over (partition by key_value order by date_modified desc) rnk
     from 
         transmission_status
     where 
         key_value = 45 
         and Field = 'Transmission Status'
) x
where 
    rnk = 1

Current output = Date_Modified = 7/11/2024
Expected output = Date_Modified = 5/15/2024  ( 2nd row)
How can I fix this to get the expected output?

Why only row two, and not also row four, which changes from Active to Inactive?

Also, what exact kind of database are you using?

I don't fully understand what you want to do. Don't you need a simply NOT EXISTS? See https://dbfiddle.uk/qJ1_benT


We need the latest date modified whenever the NEW_VALUE column changes

It took me a bit to understand this, reconciling it to only asking for the 2nd row instead of rows 2 and 4. (See the revision history for my prior interpretation). But I think I get it now, and a better problem statement looks like this:

We need the row from the final/ending NEW_VALUE status with the earliest date_modified value.

That is, first looking at just the three rows in the example data where NEW_VALUE changed from any prior value (rows 2, 4, and 7), you only want the one with the latest date_modified value (just row 2).
Or, to answer a useful question: "When did we first reach the current status?"
That out of the way, I can move forward with a solution.

First, if you want to know when a value changes from one row to the next, instead of rank() I'd tend to use lead() or lag() to look at the adjacent row.
Then, we need to know the first entry within each change. Unfortunately, I was not able to make this work without another level of nesting. But I was able to come up with this:
WITH Priors AS (
    select key_value, field, new_value, date_modified
        ,lag(new_value) over (partition by key_value, field order by date_modified) prior_value
        
    from Transmission_Status
    where key_value = 45 and Field ='Transmission Status'
), numberedChanges AS (
    select key_value, field, new_value, date_modified
      ,row_number() over (order by date_modified desc) rn
    from Priors
    where new_value <> prior_value
)
SELECT Key_Value, FIELD, New_Value, Date_Modified
FROM numberedChanges
WHERE rn = 1


https://dbfiddle.uk/8EuFC4Xc

My failing to have only one nested query was an inability to get the same rank() number for each set of New_Value records within a further key_value/field partition based on the minimum date. If I could find a way to do that, I could also add a row_number() within that partition and look for rows (the row) where both the rank and number are 1.
But what I have does work as it is, and is still likely to out-perform the alternative of joining to a GROUP BY subquery.
I'll add a final note that the WHERE and PARTITION BY clauses in the first CTE are redundant, but I expect you may want to expand the scope of this once you get the base part working, so I left both in place.

Thanks a ton to Joel Coehoorn.  The solution provided by you working .
